# Cesaro means and equivalent sequences

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, asymptotics

Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers that converges in mean (Cesaro convergence). Let $(v_n)$ be a sequence such that $v_n\sim u_n$. Does the sequence $(v_n)$ converge in mean?

---

Here is what I did.
One has $v_k=u_k(1+\varepsilon_k)$ where $\lim_{k\to+\infty}\varepsilon_k=0$.
So, $\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_k&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k(1+\varepsilon_k)\\
&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k\varepsilon_k.
\end{array}$
I know that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k$ converges, say to $L\in\mathbb C$. So, now I would like to prove that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k\varepsilon_k=0$. But I did not manage to do it.

Comment: What does $v_n \sim u_n$ mean?

Comment: And the what does it mean the symbols you use when not standard. To be precise, can you answer the Igor's comment?

Comment: I think $u_{n} \sim v_{n}$ means that $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{v_{n}} = 1$. By the way, what would be the standard notation for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$
u_n = (-1)^n \sqrt{n}
$$

and

$$
v_n = (-1)^n \sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n}.
$$

Note that $u_n \sim v_n$ as $n \to \infty$.

We have

$$
\left|\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m u_n\right| \leq \frac{1}{m} \sqrt{m} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}},
$$

so $u_n \to 0$ in mean.  But

$$
\frac{1}{m} \sum_{n=1}^{m} v_n = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{n=1}^{m} u_n + \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m} \sqrt[3]{n},
$$

and

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{m} \sqrt[3]{n} \sim \frac{3}{4} m^{4/3},
$$

so $\frac{1}{m} \sum_{n=1}^{m} v_n$ diverges to infinity.